# Is it possible to make an intent that makes intent.getData().getPath() doesn't start with /?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I would like to know, please if I control an intent and the activity that received it does :

```java
getIntent().getData().getPath()
```

is it possible to make that Path not starting with '/' .
For example if I could do it, it would start with @ the activity would go to https://good.com@evil.net/

or does the path can only start with / ?

Comment: Well which action did you use? Or from where came your intent? And what is the value of getIntent().getData().toString()?

Comment: I have an application that I'm auditing that open the url "https://example.com"+getIntent().getData().getPath(), so I ask if I can make the path starting with something else that / to be able to redirect the user to my url ?

Comment: I had already understood your question. Thats why i asked some info. You did not gave that info.

Comment: It's a MainActivity (so it is exported) and there is an intent filter with android.intent.action.VIEW and category DEFAULT and BROWSABLE, is that what you asked ?

Comment: What i asked you can read in my first comment. And you clearly gave not all info asked.

Comment: The value of getIntent().getData().toString() is whatever it can be for an intent for that activity ?

Comment: Yes. But i asked for one example only. Value of .getPath() and value of .toString().

Comment: I don't know this is why I ask the question, toString just convert something to a string no ? And I get what would be getPath for a deeplink the path of the url provided would always starts with / i think but I have no idea how can we control getPath for a basic intent ?

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that the value of .getPath() was `/@evil.net/`. That value started with a `/`. So tell the value of .toString() was the question.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to control the first character of getIntent().getData().getPath() If I control the intent sent ?

Comment: I'm trying to explain you that. But if you refuse to give some simple info. Already an hour ago you could have given that. Print or log .toString() to see.

Comment: The result of toString is the URI for a deeplink but i dont know for a basic intent

Comment: so I guess you're saying we don't control the first value if it's only an uri ? I know that for intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.fr/@test")); it will starts with / but is there another case where we can control it ? like building intent differently ?

Comment: Im still waiting for the value of .toString() where the value of .getPath() is `/@evil.net/` or `/@test`.

Comment: it is that `https://www.google.fr/@test`

Comment: Yes that is the value of the complete url contained in the Uri getInten().getData(). Now i could say that you put the leading `/` in yourself if i look at `Uri.parse("https://google.fr/@test")`. Why didnt you write `Uri.parse("https://google.fr@test")); `?

Comment: because the getPath would be empty ?

Comment: Well you can test and tell. But you could use .toString() instead. Why dont you?

Comment: I dont control the application that receive the intent, or am I misundersting your question ?

Comment: `and the activity that received it does :

getIntent().getData().getPath()` Isnt that your activity? Isnt that your code? Why would the receiver only take the path part of an uri? And not the complete url/uri?

Comment: No it is an application I'm auditing , so I only control the intent, the application redirect to "THEIRDOMAIN"+getIntent().getData().getPath() and I'm looking to know if it is vulnerable, because it doesnt specify the / so if getPath could be something not starting with a / it could be vulnerable to redirection

Comment: `or does the path can only start with / ?` Yes. The value of Uri.getPath() always starts with a `/`. It gives a string starting with the first / encountered in the url after ://.